# Do graphics cards have individual ID by which single devices can be distinguished?

Tags: windows, gpu, nvidia, amd-gpu

I have several graphics cards of the same manufacturer and same model and I want to distinguish them not only by the PCIe socket they reside in but by some individual value I can read from  the hardware. Is there such value and if so what would it be called and how could I access it?
Right now I'm using modern Nvidia cards (10xx series) and Nvidia inspector. But I'd prefer if there was any value that was also applicable to AMD.  I have programming and scripting knowledge. I am running Windows 10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a powershell example to pull information from video cards.  The DeviceID is supposed to be unique but only if the manufacturer supports Windows Display Driver Model (WDDM). (I copied this directly from learn.microsoft.com)

```
$strComputer = "." 

$colItems = get-wmiobject -class "Win32_VideoController" -namespace "root\CIMV2" ` 
-computername $strComputer 

foreach ($objItem in $colItems) { 
  write-host "Accelerator Capabilities: " $objItem.AcceleratorCapabilities 
  write-host "Adapter Compatibility: " $objItem.AdapterCompatibility 
  write-host "Adapter DAC Type: " $objItem.AdapterDACType 
  write-host "Adapter RAM: " $objItem.AdapterRAM 
  write-host "Availability: " $objItem.Availability 
  write-host "Capability Descriptions: " $objItem.CapabilityDescriptions 
  write-host "Caption: " $objItem.Caption 
  write-host "Color Table Entries: " $objItem.ColorTableEntries 
  write-host "Configuration Manager Error Code: " $objItem.ConfigManagerErrorCode 
  write-host "Configuration Manager User Configuration: " $objItem.ConfigManagerUserConfig 
  write-host "Creation Class Name: " $objItem.CreationClassName 
  write-host "Current Bits Per Pixel: " $objItem.CurrentBitsPerPixel 
  write-host "Current Horizontal Resolution: " $objItem.CurrentHorizontalResolution 
  write-host "Current Number Of Colors: " $objItem.CurrentNumberOfColors 
  write-host "Current Number Of Columns: " $objItem.CurrentNumberOfColumns 
  write-host "Current Number Of Rows: " $objItem.CurrentNumberOfRows 
  write-host "Current Refresh Rate: " $objItem.CurrentRefreshRate 
  write-host "Current Scan Mode: " $objItem.CurrentScanMode 
  write-host "Current Vertical Resolution: " $objItem.CurrentVerticalResolution 
  write-host "Description: " $objItem.Description 
  write-host "Device ID: " $objItem.DeviceID 
  write-host "Device Specific Pens: " $objItem.DeviceSpecificPens 
  write-host "Dither Type: " $objItem.DitherType 
  write-host "Driver Date: " $objItem.DriverDate 
  write-host "Driver Version: " $objItem.DriverVersion 
  write-host "Error Cleared: " $objItem.ErrorCleared 
  write-host "Error Description: " $objItem.ErrorDescription 
  write-host "ICM Intent: " $objItem.ICMIntent 
  write-host "ICM Method: " $objItem.ICMMethod 
  write-host "Inf File Name: " $objItem.InfFilename 
  write-host "Inf Section: " $objItem.InfSection 
  write-host "Installation Date: " $objItem.InstallDate 
  write-host "Installed Display Drivers: " $objItem.InstalledDisplayDrivers 
  write-host "Last Error Code: " $objItem.LastErrorCode 
  write-host "Maximum Memory Supported: " $objItem.MaxMemorySupported 
  write-host "Maximum Number Controlled: " $objItem.MaxNumberControlled 
  write-host "Maximum Refresh Rate: " $objItem.MaxRefreshRate 
  write-host "Minimum Refresh Rate: " $objItem.MinRefreshRate 
  write-host "Monochrome: " $objItem.Monochrome 
  write-host "Name: " $objItem.Name 
  write-host "Number Of Color Planes: " $objItem.NumberOfColorPlanes 
  write-host "Number Of Video Pages: " $objItem.NumberOfVideoPages 
  write-host "PNP Device ID: " $objItem.PNPDeviceID 
  write-host "Power Management Capabilities: " $objItem.PowerManagementCapabilities 
  write-host "Power Management Supported: " $objItem.PowerManagementSupported 
  write-host "Protocol Supported: " $objItem.ProtocolSupported 
  write-host "Reserved System Palette Entries: " $objItem.ReservedSystemPaletteEntries 
  write-host "Specification Version: " $objItem.SpecificationVersion 
  write-host "Status: " $objItem.Status 
  write-host "Status Information: " $objItem.StatusInfo 
  write-host "System Creation Class Name: " $objItem.SystemCreationClassName 
  write-host "System Name: " $objItem.SystemName 
  write-host "System Palette Entries: " $objItem.SystemPaletteEntries 
  write-host "Time Of Last Reset: " $objItem.TimeOfLastReset 
  write-host "Video Architecture: " $objItem.VideoArchitecture 
  write-host "Video Memory Type: " $objItem.VideoMemoryType 
  write-host "Video Mode: " $objItem.VideoMode 
  write-host "Video Mode Description: " $objItem.VideoModeDescription 
  write-host "Video Processor: " $objItem.VideoProcessor 
  write-host 
}
```

Comment: Hey thanks a lot I was guessing deviceID would be what I was looking for but from what I've read I wasn't sure if they are truly individual even if the model is the same

Comment: Also while we're at it how would I find oit the pcie index of the respective card in that loop? Just by using a counter or is there a more elegant way ?

Comment: I think the PNP Device ID is what you are looking for but not sure what kind of parsing you need to do to figure out which slot that is.  Or if there even is any parsing.

Comment: i just tested your Suggestion and for deviceid it just gives me "videocontroller1" "videocontroller2" ... thats the indexing I was looking for I guess. the pnpDeviceID seems to be individual so I guess that's what the Hardware is identified by?